# Server status for Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Hellos, I was wondering if anyone knew how to monitor server status for Google Apps Script?

It seems to have gone down today, and none of my apps worked for over an hour...

Looking at Google's server status page doesn't indicate any problems with Google Sheets, but this isn't the sheet itself, but rather the execution of the code embedded in the sheet.  https://support.google.com/a?hl=en&pli=1#topic=7570177&contact=1

Any suggestions so we can monitor this more closely?

Comment: Any error logs or error messages like error 500?

Comment: No, no error messages.  Just application hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this, I was unable to get any answers from Google, and the problem went away after about an hour.

It's still troubling that there is no way to know when the service goes down.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an outage log available within App Script. See
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/outage-log

[image: App Script Outage Log]

However, this does no include errors that you may get when trying to use App Script with a Google Sheet, which I am currently getting.

[image]